# Hyperparameter tuning and cross validation

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, hyperparameter, hyperparameter-tuning

I have some confusion about proper usage of cross-validation to

1. tune hyperparameters and
2. evaluate estimator performance and generalizeability.

As I understand it, this would be the process you would follow:

1. Split your full dataset into a training and test set (Python's `train_test_split`)
2. Use cross-validation to build a model and tune hyperparameters on the **training** set (`GridSearchCV`)
3. Evaluate the best estimator and assess generalizeability using cross-validation on the **test** set (`cross_val_score`)

I've looked through [sklearn's cross-validation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html) documentation, and it recommends still having a test set for final evaluation.

> A test set should still be held out for final evaluation, but the validation set is no longer needed when doing CV.

[sklearn's grid-search](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html#model-selection-development-and-evaluation) information recommends:

> When evaluating the resulting model it is important to do it on held-out samples that were not seen during the grid search process: it is recommended to split the data into a development set (to be fed to the GridSearchCV instance) and an evaluation set to compute performance metrics.
>
> This can be done by using the train_test_split utility function.

My issue is that I often see conflicting work (for example, just `cross_val_score` on the entire dataset, only `GridSearchCV` on the entire dataset, or just a `train_test_split` variant), and I am hoping to understand what are best practices and clarify where I may be wrong.

**Edit:** This Stack Overflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49165571/9660800) seems to answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the popular ways of splitting of data that the user can validate a model:

1. Train-Test (Most popular)
2. Train-Test-Validation
3. Train-Test-Development
4. Train-Test-Dev-Val

Every way has their own pros and cons. There is no one-size-fits-all approach for getting a perfect model. Choice is typically made by the developer considering following factors:

1. Size of data
2. Diversity of data
3. Computation budget
4. Efficiency
5. Necessity

But I would recommend K-fold CV is the best way to go with the basic train-test split model.

Thank you.

Comment: Nice idea: to still keep some dataset for the validation of the whole process...